# How do I make a 960 sticky footer in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer, sticky-footer

I'm still new to Bootstrap. If I'm designing within the 960 container and want the footer to fit correctly inside and stick to the bottom, how do I code that? Everything I find only applies to running the footer/nav across the entire view. 
Ive tried the github example and even my classmates aren't sure how to fix this.

Comment: Sorry if it seems elementary to everyone. I'm still learning.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sZrbK/

Comment: Welcome @JannaK to StackOverflow. Your question it's asking for code for an localized situation. Try to do whatever you want to do, and if you have a problem then ask a question here with some code and describe what is wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that's what people thought! I'm working on final projects so I definitely have code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS below bootstrap.css reference:

```
 <!-- CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">

      /* Sticky footer styles
      -------------------------------------------------- */

      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
      }

      /* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
      #wrap {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
        margin: 0 auto -60px;
      }

      /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
      #push,
      #footer {
        height: 60px;
      }
      #footer {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
      }

      /* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
      @media (max-width: 767px) {
        #footer {
          margin-left: -20px;
          margin-right: -20px;
          padding-left: 20px;
          padding-right: 20px;
        }
      }



      /* Custom page CSS
      -------------------------------------------------- */
      /* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

      .container {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 960px;

      }
      .container .credit {
        margin: 20px 0;
      }

    </style>
```

Then you can render the footer as follows:

```
<div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="muted credit">Example </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

NOTE: If you are experiencing problems try to set `max-width: 680px;` in `.container` at CSS code